# How do I make Accordion Click event Works?

Tags: click, accordion

Project : ATABC
When working on the Members Portal page's accordions, I found the '.click' doesn't work weridly.

HTML

```
<li class="accordion py-2" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="<?= $i * 100; ?>">
              <div class="accordion-header">
                <button aria-expanded="true"
                  class="accordion-control py-3 px-4 is-flex is-align-items-center has-text-left has-background-primary"
                  style="border:none; width:100%;" aria-controls="<?php echo $control; ?>"
                  id="<?php echo $control . '-' . $i; ?>" aria-label="<?php echo $control; ?>">
                  <div class="accordion-icon-wrapper pr-4">
                    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/icon/icon-plus-white'); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/icon/icon-minus-white'); ?>
                  </div>
                  <h4 class="accordion-title font-lg is-family-secondary has-text-white"><?php echo $header; ?></h4>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="accordion-body" id="<?php echo $control; ?>" role="region"
                aria-labelledby="<?php echo $control . '-' . $i; ?>">
                <div class="accordion-content p-5">
                  <?php echo $content; ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
```

Jquery

```
$('.accordion-body').css('display', 'none');
    $('.accordion-header').addClass('accordion-closed');
    $('.accordion-header').click(function () {
      if ($(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $(this).next().slideUp();
        $(this).removeClass('accordion-opened');
        $(this).addClass('accordion-closed');
      } else {
        $('.accordion-body').slideUp();
        $(this).next().slideDown();
        $(this).addClass('accordion-opened');
        $(this).removeClass('accordion-closed');
        $('.accordion-header').not(this).removeClass('accordion-opened');
        $('.accordion-header').not(this).addClass('accordion-closed');
      }
    });
```

I tried compare the html structure to those page that it works fine. and console.log() on each lines in the js file. and I found that it doesn't work right after the line : click event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Stackoverflow post saying that .click() works only once, when the page loads. At that time, that selector finds no elements which match that class. So no click handlers are assigned.

Since the nature of the elements changes dynamically, add the click handler to a higher-level common parent element (or just the document itself) and filter by the selector dynamically when clicked. Something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".us", function(){
//...});
```

This still adds the click handler once when the page loads, but it adds it to document. Which doesn't change. Any time document handles a click event, the (optional) second selector in the argument list is evaluated at that time to filter the source of the event before invoking the handler function.